# Entity.json(...): how to generate JSON with special characters (like ":") in the JSON key

Tags: java, json

I have an entity like

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class MyObject {
  private String name;
  private String extension;
}
```

I need to generate (for a web service) following JSON:

```
{
  "name" : "Hein Blöd"
  "extension:anybill" : "blah blah"
}
```

To generate the JSON I use `javax.ws.rs.client.Entity.json(myObject)`. The problem is the ":" in the second attribute (because ":" is an invalid character for variable names). Is there any annotation to specify the name of attribute key? Or can I  rename the generated JSON attribute in any other way?

Comment: Which lib do you use for generating json?

Comment: @alexey-r: javax.ws.rs.client.Entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t recommend mixing JAX-RS and Jackson.  Since you are using javax.ws.rs.client.Entity, you should use [@JsonbProperty](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/json/bind/annotation/JsonbProperty.html), which is part of Java EE’s JSON-P and which is intended to work with JAX-RS, on your entity class:

```
@JsonbProperty("extension:anybill")
private String extension;
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    MyObject obj = new MyObject();
    obj.name = "Hein Blöd";
    obj.extension = "blah blah";

    String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(obj);
    MyObject res = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, MyObject.class);
}

public static class MyObject {

    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("extension:anybill")
    private String extension;

}
```

Comment: Steffen is not using Jackson.

Comment: @VGR: Of course. I'm using jaxrs. But the solution works also together with jaxrs. If I want to make a pull request I can call ```myBuilder.post(Entity.json(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(myObject)));```